# Making a new cloumn in R

Tags: r

I want to make a new column in r data frame. I want to put in this column values from other column as this example :

```
ID  column1 column2 
1    C       C
2    B       C
3    A       A
4    C       B
```

The new column should have any C available in the 2 columns and its value should be present like this :

```
ID  column1 column2  new column
1    C       C        Present
2    B       C        Present 
3    A       A        Absent
4    C       B        Present
```

becuse I want the C only from the columns
Can you please help me?

Comment: you are constructing a condition (if column1 OR column2 has "C", then new column "present", else "absent"). Check how to use `ifelse()` or if you are using the tidyverse, you can use `case_when()` to construct these type of conditional operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `ifelse` with `|` operator:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(`new column`= ifelse(column1 == "C" | column2 == "C", "Present", "Absent"))
```

Output:

```
  ID column1 column2 new column
1  1       C       C    Present
2  2       B       C    Present
3  3       A       A     Absent
4  4       C       B    Present
```

Comment: Great! what if my C has multiple types like C*34:03, C* 36:21 extra .. can you help me please?

Comment: The "recipe" is to construct logical tests and combine them - in your case - with an OR (either column 1 or column2). Your add-on is about what you test for. If it follows the pattern your point out, you can use `grepl(pattern = "^C", x = coumn1) | ....`. Note that checking for regular expression allows to test for complex patterns. But, if there is a structure in your data, use a simple regex. Here we use ^ := starts with followed by a letter C. You need to adapt this to make it work for your use case. Good luck.

Comment: You can use `grepl`:  `df %>% 
    mutate(`new column`= ifelse(grepl("C", column1) | grepl("C", column2), "Present", "Absent"))
`

Answer (score 2):

This could also be used in base R:

```
DF$new_column <- Map(function(x, y) c("Absent", "Present")[any("C" %in% c(x, y)) + 1], 
                     DF$column1, DF$column2)
DF

  ID column1 column2 new_column
1  1       C       C    Present
2  2       B       C    Present
3  3       A       A     Absent
4  4       C       B    Present
```

Comment: I used that `map` a lot :D going old-school these days and trying to let go of old habits.